# Using pulse audio to share an audio stream

Tags: linux, audio, freeswitch, pulseaudio, jack

I have an application reading and writing audio to a USB audio interface (FreeSWITCH's mod_portaudio).

I need to be able to monitor this audio in another application, but the device is locked. As I understand it, pulseaudio should do this for me. (I've also tried Jack, but got nowhere with either!).

So I've installed pulseaudio, and sure enough FreeSWITCH can now only see pulse, and not the USB interface.

What steps am I missing, or what do I need to do now? I've tried creating a virtual sink & source, thinking that should show up to FreeSWITCH, and I should then be able to map it somehow, but I'm going nowhere fast! What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: We'll need evidence of your setup. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can improve your Q so people can create a minimal and testable environment that matches your situation. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong site then. I'm talking about what I need to do in order to share an audio device; the components are academic, to a degree, but to replicate it you could install FreeSWITCH?!

Comment: This Q is too general. Even if we had all of the gear/software that you are using, we only know from you that "it's not working".  To help, people need to better understand what you have tried so they can guess/try-to-understand why it's not working. I would see if the "followers" for your tags (pulseaudio, freeswitch and jack) have higher counts on superuser.com S.E. sites *may not* be the right place to be asking. IMHO, I would look for more specialized support forums or blogs. All this said, I'll be happy for you if someone offers you a working answer. Good luck!